# Read file lines into one string seperated by \r\n

Tags: c, io

I need to read a file that looks like

```
foo
bar
foobar
barfoo
```

in C and save it to a `char buf[]` that looks like `"foo\r\nbar\r\nfoobar\r\nbarfoo\r\n"`

Currently I am trying to use fgets() but im not sure how I can add the \r\n into the char[] that I have

```
void client(char* server_host) {
    int rc, client_socket;
    char buf[BUFFER_LEN];
    client_socket = connect_to_server(server_host, NON_RESERVED_PORT);
    printf("\nEnter a line of text to send to the server or EOF to exit\n");
    while(fgets(buf, BUFFER_LEN, stdin) != NULL) {
        send_msg(client_socket, buf, strlen(buf) + 1);
        rc = recv_msg(client_socket, buf);
        buf[rc] = '\0';
        printf("client received %d bytes  :%s: \n", rc, buf);
        printf("\nEnter a line of text to send to the server or EOF to exit\n");
    }
}
```

This is the way I'm trying to do this, but when I use the send_msg() I need the buf that I'm using to be seperated by the \r\n delimeter on each line that I read in.

Comment: Do you only get `\n` in the socket?

Comment: Added the part that I'm dealing with

Comment: Does the file you read from contain `\r\n`? If so, have you opened it in binary mode?

Comment: There should be a code section to use (surround the code by a pair of ```s).

Comment: fgets() right now is just reading one line and stopping when it sees the \n. I want to loop through the whole file and put it into a string with \r\n separating the lines

Comment: @BeanBop Does the file you read from contain `\r\n`? How did you open the file? Please show a [mre].

Comment: I cannot figure out how to copy from my terminal using VIM and get it to paste her properly. I am using ``` ```

Comment: Look at how I edited it.

Comment: Thank you @TedLyngmo

Comment: @BeanBop You're welcome. Btw `fgets(buf, BUFFER_LEN, stdin)` isn't reading from a file - it's reading from the terminal.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ya sorry so im using cat on the file and redirecting that to stdin

Comment: You can't use the same `buf` for reading each line and also saving all the lines.

Comment: I dont need my code to stay exactly like this. Just wondering if there is a way to read a file and then save the entire file to a string with \r\n as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're saying you have a buffer `buf` that contains something like

```c
{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 0 }
```

```c
{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 }            // In the case of a line that's longer than BUF_SIZE-1.
```

But you want a buffer that contains

```c
{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\r', '\n' }   // send_msg doesn't care about the NUL.
```

```c
{ 'a', 'b', 'c' }
```

It's just a question of checking if the last character is a LF, and replacing the LF and NUL with CR and LF.

```c
...
while (fgets(buf, BUFFER_LEN, stdin) != NULL) {
    size_t len = strlen(buf);
    if (buf[len-1] != '\n') {
       // The line didn't fit in the buffer.
       send_msg(client_socket, buf, len);
       continue;
    }

    buf[len-1] = '\r';
    buf[len] = '\n';
    ++len;
    send_msg(client_socket, buf, len);

    ...
}
...
```

This code doesn't handle NULs entered by the user well. It's [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) situation as far as this answer is concerned.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am trying to do. I will try to get this to work with my code. Was really hoping there was an easy solution but I guess in C its a bit more complicated to do this.

Comment: Since `fgets` only reads until a LF, it can only be at the end, which greatly simplifies things. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you this solution makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Hacker corner: `buf[len-1]` is UB when the first character read is a _null character_.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, oh right, I considered that, but thought a leading NU would meant an empty input which means EOF which means the loop isn't entered. Of course, that's wrong. An actual NUL could have been provided. Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky, yet minimal code.

```
char buf[BUFFER_LEN];

// Read up to 2 less to be sure we have room for an added \r\n
while(fgets(buf, BUFFER_LEN - 2, stdin)) {

  // Use strcspn() to find offset of \n if it exists or the string length
  // Then write \r\n\ there
  strcpy(buf + strcspn(buf, "\n"), "\r\n");

  // send it
  send_msg(client_socket, buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

Comment: Note: This inserts `\r\n` mid line if the line is longer than `BUFFER_LEN - 2` chars.

Comment: @ikegami True that.  OP is quiet on long lines.  We could use `fgetc()`, one-by-one, yet that incurs much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This may be total overkill for the task at hand, but I like to encapsulate data in `struct`s and create support functions for those `struct`s. It takes some time for all the boilerplate but it's usually nice when it's done.

Here I've made a `struct` and `typedef`ined into `String`. It has a `char*` for the actual data, the `size` of the data and the `capacity` - which is how much data it's capable of currently holding.

```
typedef struct {
    char *data;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
} String;
```

To deal with such a `String`, I'd start by creating these support functions - hopefully with self explanatory names and signatures:

```
String *String_create();
void String_destroy(String *s);
bool String_append(String *s, const char *rhs, size_t len);
bool String_getline(String *s, FILE *fp);
```

That's the minimal set of functions we need for this - but if anything else pops up, you can certainly add further `String` functions.

Example implementation:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *data;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
} String;

String* String_create() {
    String *s = malloc(sizeof *s);         // allocate a String struct
    if(s) {
        s->size = 0;                       // initialize its values
        s->capacity = 10;
        s->data = malloc(s->capacity + 1); // some initial capacity + '\0'
        if(s->data == NULL) {
            free(s);                       // deal with allocation problems
            return NULL;
        }
        s->data[0] = '\0';                 // null terminate
    }
    return s;
}

void String_destroy(String *s) {           // deallocates a String
    free(s->data);
    free(s);
}

// Append to an existing string
bool String_append(String *s, const char *rhs, size_t len) {
    if(s->size + len > s->capacity) {        // check capacity
        // not enough space in the String - need to increase it

        size_t nc = (s->size + len) * 5 / 3; // make it grow some
        char* ns = realloc(s->data, nc + 1); // allocate more space
        if(ns == NULL) return false;         // could not increase capacity
        s->capacity = nc;                    // set new capacity
        s->data = ns;                        // and the new data pointer
    }
    // append rhs to our String
    memcpy(s->data + s->size, rhs, len);
    s->size += len;
    s->data[s->size] = '\0';                 // ... and null terminate
    return true;
}

// Convenience wrappers for the String_append function
bool String_append_char(String *s, char ch) {
    return String_append(s, &ch, 1);
}

bool String_append_String(String *s, const String *rhs) {
    return String_append(s, rhs->data, rhs->size);
}

// Read a line into a String from a stream
bool String_getline(String *s, FILE *fp) {
    s->size = 0;                             // zero out this String
    int ch;
    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {         // read until EOF
        // call the above append function
        if(String_append_char(s, ch) == false) return false;
        if(ch == '\n') return true;          // newline, return success
    }
    return s->size != 0;                     // at EOF, did we get some data?
}
```

With that boilerplate, reading everything from the file into a `String` could be done like this:

```
int main() {
    String* str = String_create();      // The final String
    String* tmp = String_create();      // A temporary String to read lines

    while(String_getline(tmp, stdin)) { // Read lines until that fails
        // The String is at least one char long if String_getline succeeds so
        // this is safe:
        if(tmp->data[tmp->size-1] == '\n') { // got newline
            tmp->data[tmp->size-1] = '\r';   // replace it with \r
            String_append_char(tmp, '\n');   // and add \n
        }

        // Append this String to the final String
        if(String_append_String(str, tmp) == false) {
            printf("Could not append %s to %s\n", tmp->data, str->data);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    String_destroy(tmp);               // not needed anymore

    send_msg(client_socket, str->data, str->size + 1);

    String_destroy(str);
}
```